# How to do jest mocking for non-exist external dependency

Tags: unit-testing, jestjs, jest-fetch-mock

I am trying to mock external dependency which is not yet published in npm repository.

```
import Utils from 'external-dependency';
jest.mock('external-dependency', () => ({
default: ()=> jest.fn()
}));
```

Above jest mocking display following error since that dependency not yet exist.

> Cannot find module 'external-dependency'

How to mock non-exist dependency in Jest?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As stated in [the reference](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/jest-object#jestmockmodulename-factory-options),

> The third argument can be used to create virtual mocks – mocks of modules that don't exist anywhere in the system

Also notice that `jest.mock` return value translates to CommonJS module by default. In case of ES module, it should be:

```
jest.mock('external-dependency', () => ({
  __esModule: true,
  default: ()=> jest.fn()
}), {virtual: true});
```